# dealing with curved ribs in a flat rib recipe

Tags: pork, slow-cooking, ribs

I'm trying to make a pork rib ragu, and the ribs I have got are rather... curled. the recipe doesn't really specify which ribs to get, but in the video they're rather flat, making browning them, and then simmering them in stock look much easier.

Should I just roll with my curled ribs, or should I be trying to crack them down to a flat state before browning them?

Comment: It may be easier to brown them in a round bottom wok if you have one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different cuts of ribs have different degrees of curve to them. In my experience, baby back ribs are the most curved, and St. Louis cut spareribs are the flatest (although that is a relative term). [This page](http://amazingribs.com/recipes/porknography/pork_cuts.html) has a chart showing where the different cuts of ribs come from in the rib cage in case you're interested.

I wouldn't try to flatten the ribs; I can't imagine of any way to do that other than breaking the bones.

Comment: yeah breaking the bone was what I was going to do.

Comment: There's no reason to anyway, curve shouldn't affect the end product.

Answer (score 1):

Go with them the way they are - you sometimes have to live with your ingredients. I'd slice them, then brown on both sides and the top - should be fine.